# Cannot read more then 255 characters from MEMO field using ADODB with VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I am trying to read/write MEMO type field from an Access 2.0 file using ADODB. I can write data into the MEMO field - more than 255 characters (when I open converted file in Access I can see all data that is supposed to be there), but I cannot read more than 255 characters using the VB6 code as bellow. `rst("Opis")` is the memo field I am interested in:

```
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & T_BAZA & ";Persist Security Info=False"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Opis FROM JadlospisSzczegoly WHERE Opis IS NOT NULL AND NazwaJadlospisu='" & LCase(Me.Combo3.Text) & "' AND Dzien=" & t_Dzien & " AND Posilek=" & t_Posilek
rst.Open SQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = Trim$(rst("Opis"))
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: `DISTINCT` clause is incompatible with MEMO

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. DISTINCT in SQL query was the problem. I have read that DISTINCT with memo datatype does not work as it should be.

When I have removed it, all characters from the MEMO filed were displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [GetChunk()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/appendchunk-and-getchunk-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15) method:

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
    If rst.Fields("Opis").ActualSize > 0 Then
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = rst.Fields("Opis").GetChunk(rst.fields("Opis").ActualSize)
    Else
        Me.RichTextBox1.Text = "n/a"
    End If
   rst.MoveNext
Loop
```